# If an $H\le G$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $d$, then show $G$ has an irreducible representation of at least dimension $d$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, and let $\rho :H\to GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation of dimension $d$. Prove that there is an irreducible representation of $G$ whose dimension is at least $d$.

This is a homework problem I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how to begin. I am assuming I have to apply properties of induced representation, but I am not sure where to begin.

It should be noted we have covered both Frobineus reciprocity and Mackey's irreducibility criterion.

I tried taking the induced representation of $\rho$, since that is all I can do. But the problem is that it may not be irreducible. I want to use Mackey, but I don't feel like I have enough information to apply it. Again any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You can see directly from the definition $\rho \uparrow^G$ that its restriction to $H$ has an irreducible submodule isomorphic to (the image of) $\rho$. That would not be possible if all of the composition factors of $\rho\uparrow^G $ had dimension less than $d$.

This arguments is valid for representations over arbitrary fields, whereas arguments involving ordinary characters only work in characteristic 0, and the problem made no assumptions about the field of the representation.

Comment: Nice. (I deleted my answer since yours is much simpler.)